# Full width 2 Column Image & Text Section css grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Hi everybody i am new with css grid would somebody please help me i am trying to make Fullwidth 2 Column Image & Text Section  i was trying on YouTube to find how but it cant so just make example  and css please
Thank you in advance.

Something like this

[image]

Comment: Are you new to CSS or CSS-Grid? why don't you use `display: flex`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, if it's only for that simple layout, flexbox would be a good solution.

Since you asked for a css grid solution, here you go:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.column {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}

.column:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">image</div>
  <div class="column">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use any css framework.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">image</div>
  <div class="col">content</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

So simple :).